# Hosting multiple subdomains on a different Apache server

Tags: linux, apache, server, ubuntu-16.04

We host our website on a Microsoft server. For reasons I'm not going to explain here, we decided to host 3 subdomains on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.

My question is how to configure the virtual hosts on Apache for this.

I have (I think) all the info I need [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04).

My doubt is: As ServerName I'm going to write the subdomain (see example below), right? Basically, I'm going to treat the subdomains as if I had 3 different websites.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/sudomain1.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName sudomain1.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sudomain1.example.com/public_html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/sudomain2.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName sudomain2.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sudomain2.example.com/public_html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/sudomain3.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName sudomain3.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sudomain3.example.com/public_html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And the question is? Have you tried the above virtual host configuration? Did it work? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. The question is if I should treat a subdomain as a separate website or not. 
I know it would be preferable to test something before asking, and trust me I break my head always before asking someone, but this is something that I cannot test but directly implement in the production server, so I was hoping to find anyone who at least did it once.

Comment: The above looks fine to me. I am use to setup two virtual host for my projects, one for example `project.domain.com` and then `markup-project.domain.com` of which both have its own virtual host configuration. Since both virtual host are related I store them in the same file i.e `/etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf`. Of course you first need to test this with a demo setup. Just add some fictive domains and then in your hosts file e.g `/etc/hosts` point each domain to the ip of the server.